# Increment a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, increment

I am trying to increment a variable using Javascript, but I am not quite understanding what I am doing wrong. What do I need to change?

```
function init(){
    var a = 0;
}

function repeat(){
    a = a+1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Variables have scope. Your `var a` isn't reachable outside the `init()` function. That said... there's a serious lack of information in your question.

Comment: This is very primary error. You really should read some good javascript introduction : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this ?

```
var a;
function init(){
    a = 0;
}
function repeat(){
    a = a+1;
}
```

If `a` is declared in a function, it's not available outside this function.

See [the MDN on var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) :

> The scope of a variable declared with var is the enclosing function
>   or, for variables declared outside a function, the global scope (which
>   is bound to the global object).

Answer (score 0):

```
function init(){
  var a=0;

  a = repeat(a);
}
function repeat(a){
 return a+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, access to variables declared inside a function is possible only inside this function. This rule also applies to curly braces.

Also to increment your value you may use postfix or prefix.
Postfix: `x++` the increment operator increments and returns the value before incrementing.

Prefix `++x` the increment operator increments and returns the value after incrementing.

```
{
  let x = 0
  x = myFunc(x)
}

function myFunc(a){
 return a++
}

// next line will throw error because x was declared inside braces
// Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Amazing to see an answer to my question asked 10 years ago! Also amazing how little I knew back then :)